# How can I "stick" objects to tables in Skyrim and still allow those objects to be player-interactable?

Tags: havok, skyrim-modding

I'm trying to place a non-static pot (`RuinsPot01`) on a table (`RuinsAltar`) with the Havok simulation.

I place the pot a little bit above the table and turn on Havok. The pot falls down but is left floating slightly above the table.

If I turn of Havok and press `F` it is aligned correctly to the table, but as soon I turn on Havok Simulation, it jumps up slightly and floats as before.

Does any one have a fix for this? Making the pot static isn't an option, it has to be movable.

Comment: Do other tables work any better? Do other items sit better on that table?

Comment: Seems like a fairly broad question. There are a number of things that could be causing that behavior. You'll likely get better help on a forum specific to the Creation Kit or Havok.

Comment: I have the same problem with "any" object placed with Havok on "any" surface. I solved it by placing them with "F" and then turn on "Don't Havok Settle" in the object's property dialogue. This makes them still non-static but they will not "float up"...

Comment: [Questions about mods are on-topic here](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here), folks. That said, this question is a touch unclear. Pictures would help.

Comment: That and if you have found a solution can you please write it as an Answer - answering your own questions is encouraged.

Comment: Is it possible the pot is floating because it's bounding box is slightly too large and it's pushing it up? (not an answer just a suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

This is a general answer for most 3d physincs engines, you can use one or both of this solutions:

1-) A solid object should have have the possibility of setting  an inactive state, then the engine will not run any physic calculation for it until its first collision with any other object.

2-) Using proxy objects: The visible objects doesn't need to be the same that the physical object. You can use a proxy object scaled down a bit inside the visual object to fill the space between collisions.

That empty space between colliding objects is not a bug, is necessary for performance, when doing collision detection calculations. The engine should allow you to modify that value, if you set this value too small performance issues can arise and even wrong behavior like objects trespassing each other.

This answer is based experience using the same Havok engine in 3ds Max.